# powershell Rename-Item fail to rename

Tags: powershell, file-rename

My powershell script:

```powershell
$dst = 'C:\Temp'

#Get all folders in $dst
$folders = Get-ChildItem $dst | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }

foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    $cnt = (Get-ChildItem -filter *.txt $folder | Measure-Object).Count

    $base = ($folder.FullName -split " \[.*\]$")[0]
    $newname = $("{0} [{1}]" -f $base,$cnt)

    Write-Host $folder.FullName "->" $newname

    Rename-Item $folder.FullName $newname
}
```

**The problem**

On my first run I get this:

```powershell
PS C:\Temp> C:\Temp\RenameFolders.ps1
C:\Temp\m1 -> C:\Temp\m1 [1]
```

On my second run I get this:

```powershell
PS C:\Temp> C:\Temp\RenameFolders.ps1
C:\Temp\m1 [1] -> C:\Temp\m1 [0]
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Temp\m1 [1]' does not exist.
At C:\Temp\RenameFolders.ps1:15 char:5
+     Rename-Item $folder.FullName $newname
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I know that the problem is in '[' and ']', but I realy can't understand why.

Can someone explain me why is that a problem?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like before/after? What are you expecting to occur exactly?

Comment: as you can see in my example... start name: "C:\Temp\m1", after rename: "C:\Temp\m1 [1]", after second run... start name: "C:\Temp\m1 [1]", rename to "C:\Temp\m1 [0]" <- this step fails

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are running PS 3+ add *-LiteralPath* switch to your rename:

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $folder.FullName $newname
```

otherwise use `Move-Item`

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath $folder.FullName $newname
```

Powershell doesn't like square brackets in filenames, more in the following [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bbd9fa31-d982-45b7-b8e4-37b333918c0e/powershell-doesnt-like-pathname-with-square-brackets-?forum=winserverpowershell):

> This became an issue with V2 when they added the square brackets to the wildcard character set to support "blobbing".

From `get-help about_wildcards`:

> Windows PowerShell supports the following wildcard characters.
>
> Wildcard Description        Example  Match             No match
>
> ---
>
> - Matches zero or    a*       A, ag, Apple      banana
>             more characters
>
>   ?        Matches exactly    ?n       an, in, on        ran
>             one character in
>             the specified
>             position
>
>   [ ]      Matches a range    [a-l]ook book, cook, look  took
>             of characters
>
>   [ ]      Matches specified  [bc]ook  book, cook        hook
>             characters

`[` and `]` are special characters.

Comment: Thank you so much! `-LiteralPath` worked perfectly for me. Why?

Comment: See above article: `...This became an issue with V2 when they added the square brackets to the wildcard character set to support "blobbing"`

Comment: Thank you so so much! - Square brackets in filenames had me completely messed up! -LiteralPath fixed it for me!