# Rename Folders to match filename inside

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of folders that I need changed as follows:

**before:**

- FolderNamedX (2016)

  - fileNamedY.png

**after:**

- NamedSameAsFileWithin (2016)

  - fileNamedY.png

Essentially, folder name needs to change to match the name of the file inside it and retain the year at the same time.

I am trying to do this using PowerShell.
Any kind soul can steer me in the right direction?

I am very new to PowerShell and so far I have something like this (don't laugh too hard):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Lab" | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $Filename = Filename.Trim(".png") # Not sure how to retrieve the filename from current folder
    $OldFolderName = $_.Name
    $NewFolderNameLeft, $NewFolderNameRight = $OldFolderName.Split("(")
    $NewFolderNameLeft = $Filename
    Rename-item -Path $_.Name -NewName ($NewFolderNameLeft+"("+$NewFolderNameRight) -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your work. It goes a long way here.

Comment: Is is always the last character that changes before the year? There is only the one png in the folders?

Comment: Your code changes the folder to match the file within. Your example is just changing a single char. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks (for not laughing too hard:). Sorry, i  should edit it, its the entire folder name that needs changing, except for the year in round brackers. Sorry for miscommunication. Also, the folders have other files in them but always only the one .png which I am targeting.

Comment: Perfect. That is clear now.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the get the name of the file inside the current directory, so the code in line two is obviously very misleading. I tried experimenting with -Recurse but that doesn't lead me anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havent had a chance to test yet but this should work. Leaving the `-whatif` and you already have the environment to test with.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Lab" | Where-Object{$_.PSisContainer} | ForEach-Object -Process {
    # Get the filename without the extension
    $pngName = Get-ChildItem $_ -Filter "*.png" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace ".*\(","$pngName (") -WhatIf
}
```

Get each folder under the path. Then for each of those folders return the base name of the PNG within. Use that to replace everything before the first open brackets. A *very* simple regex ensures that. The could be bad if there are folders without png's in them so you need to be careful and possibly build in some logic to account for that.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. Now i am going to try and digest it thoroughly since a lot of this is over my head.

Comment: I am given an error: Invalid regular expressions pattern: .*(. Trying to figure it out. Funny enough i started reading about regex today

Comment: @Norskyi That's probably a typo in @Matt's script, where `(` is a special character in a regular expression, so if you want to match them in the pattern, they need to be escaped with `\ ` before them like `\(`. Otherwise they go in pairs `(  )` and give instructions to the regex engine about how to group different bits of the text together.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, thanks! that was it. Works wonderfully. Completely different than what I imagined the code to be.

Comment: Matt, TessellatingHeckler, I really appreciate both of your times. I am still digesting the code.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yes that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Just got home and studied the code. I think pretty much got it comfortably enough to say i know exactly what its doing. Regex needs some work to wrap my mind around though (the ".*" part) regexr.com helped. I tested it and it works great!

Comment: In addition to the code I also now want to rename the filename to match the newly renamed folder name (ie FileNamedY (2016)). Is this the correct way to go about: `Get-ChildItem $_ -Filter "*.png" | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name + ".png")`

Comment: Ran into a small issue with some folders containing [ ] in the name, as "FolderNamedX (2016) [HIGH]". The script gives me an error for these folders "Rename-Item : `Cannot rename because item at 'D:\Lab\FolderNamedX (2016) [HIGH]' does not exist.` Is [ ] a sacred animal ? :)

Comment: I think I answered my own question **[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268463/powershell-rename-item-fail-to-rename)**. Time to install PS 3

Answer (score 1):

```cs
# Process all the subdirectories in d:\test
# (ignore any files)
Get-ChildItem -Directory "d:\test\" | ForEach {

    # Get the .png files in each directory; get the first file 
    # (so it doesn't break if there's more than one)
    $fileName = Get-ChildItem $_ -File -Name *.png | Select -First 1

    # Rename the directory with a regular expression pattern
    # which puts in the file's BaseName (name with no extension).
    #
    # The regular expression matches anything up to the first " ("
    # i.e. everything before " (2016)" gets replaced, but that is kept.
    #
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.Name -replace '.*(?= \()', $fileName.BaseName)

}
```

Only lightly tested.

Comment: You need to specify png as there are other files in the directory and that this code requires PowerShell 3.0. I had wanted to do a positive lookahead but was trying to keep the regex down. Good work

Comment: Edited it to only look for PNG files, that makes sense; I didn't see the comment about other files existing.

Comment: It seems I am running PowerShell 2.0. I guess this code won't work for me until I install the version 3.

Comment: @Norskyi Ah, maybe you can't do `gci -Directory` in v2, I don't track the differences in versions very closely. And your findings about square brackets in filenames is interesting, I didn't know that at all.